# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli::execute()

Tags: php, mysqli

I am learning php. I am getting this error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli::execute() in C:\xampp\htdocs\search\index.php:58 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\search\index.php on line 58

Here the line 58 is

```
<?php
    include'config.php';
    $stmt=$conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM info");
    $conn->execute(); // This line
    $result=$stmt->get_result();
 ?>
```

I am trying to create a simple live search.

Comment: You are trying to “execute” your connection, you need to execute the statement instead.

Comment: Oh yah  Thanks. It's working now.

Answer (score 0):

Call the method `execute()` on `$stmt` object instead.

```
 include 'config.php';
 $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM info");
 $stmt->execute(); // you are executing connection here
 $result = $stmt->get_result();
```